# When a creature is hit with the Wizard's Sleep, do they also have to save against the initial slow effect?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, saving-throw, unconscious

The Wizard Level 1 Daily spell Sleep says:

> Hit: The target is slowed (save ends).
>   If the target fails its first saving
>   throw against this power, the target
>   becomes unconscious (save ends).

So say a creature fails it's first saving throw and becomes **unconscious (save ends)**.

Does the creature have to save separately or together against both **unconscious** and **slow**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current text reads:

> **First Failed Saving Throw:** The target is unconscious instead of slowed (save ends).

This was clarified in Essentials, and the errata was back ported to [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=451).